# Initialising float matrix inside function

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I got this problem when trying to initialize global c++ matrix(2D array) inside a function:

here is what I'm doing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

float matrix[5][5];

void setIR(){
    matrix[5][5]= {
        { 17.2, 22.75, 2.5, -9.15, 0.2},
        { 22.75, 145.5, 9.25, 20.75, 5.25 },
        { 2.5, 9.25, 76.5, -15.5, -6.0 },
        { -9.15, 20.75, -15.5, 37.3, -25.65 },
        { 0.2, 5.25, -6.0, -25.65, 41.2 }
        };

int main(){
//rest of the code
......
}
```

I'm getting only bunch of

```
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(46): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(46): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(47): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(48): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(48): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(48): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(50): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(50): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(50): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(51): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\apple\documents\visual studio2010\projects\jcb\jcb\jcbPIO.cpp(51): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

I'm doing something wrong or C++ limitation ?

Comment: If you want a C++ solution I recommend you change to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. You can only initialise an array where it is declared. In your case, move the initialisation to the file scope declaration and delete `setIR`.

Comment: Alternately, if you **really** need to delay initialization for some reason (or want to be able to re-initialize), you could always use a nested loop. Or keep a copy that is initialized on compile, and memcpy it to the one you'll be using (and possibly modifying?) at runtime.

Comment: can't  do with std::vector or std::array, need to change the whole implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "list assignment" syntax only works for initialization (that is, at the place where you define the variable), not for assignment. What your assignment statement tries to do is to assign to the single element `matrix[5][5]` (which doesn't actually exist) a values given by the curly braces list, which isn't a valid syntax for a value.

You can assign the matrix as follows:

```
float matrix[5][5];

void setIR()
{
  static float const values[5][5]= {
        { 17.2, 22.75, 2.5, -9.15, 0.2},
        { 22.75, 145.5, 9.25, 20.75, 5.25 },
        { 2.5, 9.25, 76.5, -15.5, -6.0 },
        { -9.15, 20.75, -15.5, 37.3, -25.65 },
        { 0.2, 5.25, -6.0, -25.65, 41.2 }
        };
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
      matrix[i][j] = values[i][j];
}
```

Of course, given that your values are constants anyway, the best solution is to just give them in the definition of `matrix` itself. That also saves the time to copy all the data.

Comment: Thank you all. The whole time I was initializing one single element with 5x5 array elements. I think I'll stick to initializing during array definition

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the `{}` initialiser syntax on initialisation, and you can only initialise a global variable at its definition.

For this situation, you could initialise a different matrix and then just copy the contents:

```
void setIR(){
    static const float init[5][5]= {
        { 17.2, 22.75, 2.5, -9.15, 0.2},
        { 22.75, 145.5, 9.25, 20.75, 5.25 },
        { 2.5, 9.25, 76.5, -15.5, -6.0 },
        { -9.15, 20.75, -15.5, 37.3, -25.65 },
        { 0.2, 5.25, -6.0, -25.65, 41.2 }
    };
    memcpy(matrix, init, sizeof(matrix));
}
```

If you're not a fan of things like `memcpy` then you could manually copy by looping, or try to use the STL, but in my opinion this is the simplest and shortest solution in this case.

Comment: May as well make the array `static`

Comment: For 5x5 this is OK, but 1000x1000, damn memory

Comment: What about memory? If it's 1000x1000 then those million floats have to be stored *somewhere*. Might as well be in a contiguous ~4MB block.

Comment: OK. Static array, 4mb; memcpy call, another 4mb.  If I need more than 1000x1000, I will need twice the amount of memory right ? And my colleague that is next to me will say "Hey man, wtf you're doing with my memory?"